# PHP Elasticsearch, bool query with filter not getting any result

Tags: php, elasticsearch

So I'm trying to find all the documents that contains "ssh" in the "name" field, where the field "versions" equals to 12.1.2,  12.1.1, ...
Here are my parameters:

```
$params = [
            'index' => 'notes',
            'type' => 'release',
            'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            'match' => [ 'name' => 'ssh' ]
                            ],
                        'filter' => [
                            'term' => [ 'versions' => '12.1.2, 12.1.1, 12.1.0' ]
                            ]   
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```

Here's an Example document:

```
    Array
(
    [_index] => notes
    [_type] => release
    [_id] => AVo3jnT2RJ1Gn1RjrM7p
    [_score] => 0.52541894
    [_source] => Array
        (
            [name] => 621423 : sys-icheck reports error with /config/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
            [component] => TMOS
            [symptoms] => On Azure cloud, running sys-icheck may report an error with /config/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key and other files:  ERROR: missing /config/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key ERROR: missing /config/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub ERROR: missing /config/ssh/ssh_host_key ERROR: missing /config/ssh/ssh_host_key.pub
            [conditions] => This occurs on BIG-IP running on Azure cloud.
            [impact] => sys-icheck utility indicates an error. The sys-icheck utility is used to find file system changes that have occurred since initial installation and provide information about their status.
            [workaround] => 
            [fix] => Fixed an issue with files in /config/ssh/ that was causing sys-icheck to report errors.
            [versions] => 12.1.2, 12.1.1, 12.1.0
        )

)
```

As requested, here's the `name` mapping:

```
{
    notes: {
        mappings: {
            release: {
                name: {
                    full_name: "name"
                    mapping: {
                        name: {
                            type: "text"
                            fields: {
                                keyword: {
                                    type: "keyword"
                                    ignore_above: 256
                                } -
                            } -
                        } -
                    } -
                } -
            } -
        } -
    } -
}
```

Result from /GET/notes:

```
    {
    notes: {
        aliases: {}
        mappings: {
            release: {
                properties: {
                    component: {
                        type: "text"
                        fields: {
                            keyword: {
                                type: "keyword"
                                ignore_above: 256
                            } -
                        } -
                    } -
                    conditions: {
                        type: "text"
                        fields: {
                            keyword: {
                                type: "keyword"
                                ignore_above: 256
                            } -
                        } -
                    } -
                    fix: {
                        type: "text"
                        fields: {
                            keyword: {
                                type: "keyword"
                                ignore_above: 256
                            } -
                        } -
                    } -
                    impact: {
                        type: "text"
                        fields: {
                            keyword: {
                                type: "keyword"
                                ignore_above: 256
                            } -
                        } -
                    } -
                    name: {
                        type: "text"
                        fields: {
                            keyword: {
                                type: "keyword"
                                ignore_above: 256
                            } -
                        } -
                    } -
                    symptoms: {
                        type: "text"
                        fields: {
                            keyword: {
                                type: "keyword"
                                ignore_above: 256
                            } -
                        } -
                    } -
                    versions: {
                        type: "text"
                        fields: {
                            keyword: {
                                type: "keyword"
                                ignore_above: 256
                            } -
                        } -
                    } -
                    workaround: {
                        type: "text"
                        fields: {
                            keyword: {
                                type: "keyword"
                                ignore_above: 256
                            } -
                        } -
                    } -
                } -
            } -
        } -
        settings: {
            index: {
                creation_date: "1486999820715"
                number_of_shards: "5"
                number_of_replicas: "1"
                uuid: "SZfFCZ-HRT6Yr17epsv2-Q"
                version: {
                    created: "5020099"
                } -
                provided_name: "notes"
            } -
        } -
    } -
}
```

The filter is the only working statement, since I get all the 12.1.2 documents. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show a sample document that you think should match?

Comment: @Val Here's a sample document

Comment: `name` field must have `ssh`

Comment: @BhavikPatel yup, bad example, let me edit that document

Comment: also, could you tell us your `name` field's `mapping` ?

Comment: @BhavikPatel here you go

Comment: @NinjaDuck can you update your question with the result you get when calling `curl -XGET localhost:9200/notes` ?

Comment: Is there a way to obtain this with REST? I can't get cURL to work

Comment: You can use any HTTP client, `wget`, Sense, the `head` plugin, Postman, etc, just `GET /notes`

Comment: @Val a few braces might have been lost in manual formatting, don't pay attention to that

Comment: it seems you have a `query` field in your mapping that shouldn't be there... you have probably `PUT` a query instead of `POST`ing it, right?

Comment: @Val ... I might have done that by accident. That would explain a lot

Comment: Any chance to properly reindex your data and try again? Or maybe just create another clean index and index a few sample documents to make sure this works fine?

Comment: @Val I did create a new index, and re-inserted the exact same content. This time, using the query I posted, I don't get a single result

Comment: Can you update the mapping above with the real mapping of the new index you created so we have the most up-to-date info?

Comment: @Val I updated the mapping and the /GET/ result. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query works for me, i.e. you need to use a `terms` query for `versions` and have an array with each version.

```
 $params = [
        'index' => 'notes',
        'type' => 'release',
        'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        'match' => [ 'name' => 'ssh' ]
                    ],
                    'filter' => [
                        'terms' => [ 
                            'versions' => ['12.1.2', '12.1.1', '12.1.0']
                        ]   
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because `analyzer` of the field `name` is set to `keyword` . When you do this it will not tokenize the keywords. Hence here you will have to use the whole text to search that document.

Meaning if you use below in your `must` it will give you your output.

```
621423 : sys-icheck reports error with /config/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

Check out the `keyword anlyzer` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html)

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do about that. Thanks!

Comment: It's not true, the analyzer of the `name` field is `standard` (= the default analyzer for `text` fields). The `keyword` analyzer is used for the `name.keyword` field.